# how to call python from PHP exec

Tags: python, php

how to call python script in php code with exec
I think there is some permission problem. maybe www-data can not access `pymysql`.
and I try with sudo after I put ALL permission to www-data. but It doesn't work.

I know it is not normal case to call python script from php. but there is some reason to what I have to do this.!!

please help me to use pymysql !!

index.php and index.py are in the same directory!. It is not path problem!

```
# php file
$result = exec('/usr/bin/python3 index.py', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($result, $output, $return_var);



# python file
import pymysql
print("success")


# linux command
python3 -m install PyMysql
pip list : PyMySQL    0.9.3
pip3 list : PyMySQL    0.9.3


# ps aux | grep httpd
apache 

# whoami
www-data
```

the error is : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Comment: `pip list` is probably listing python 2 packages. Try `pip3`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it has the same list with pip and pip3

Comment: when you run the python script directly, it works?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Yes, I works very well!!

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? What does `which python3` return? Perhaps it is not `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @jdaz It is the same. I pretty sure the python is /usr/bin/python3. `exec("which python3")` return `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Probably, when you run Python from the shell, the environment variable `PYHTONPATH` is set to point to the directory where `pymysql` is installed, and in the environment under which PHP runs, it is not set. Try setting `PYTHONPATH` in PHP before invoking the Python script.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron the python path is ~/usr/bin/ and I added it and site-pages directory too. like this `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")`  but it doesn't work. `$pip3 show pymysql` return `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`